# Extract Star Rating from Trip Advisor

Tags: xml, r, web-crawler, data-extraction, rvest

For my self learning purpose(web crawling), i want to extract ratings given by user from trip advisor website. Below is the code i have written in R but its not working. Can you please suggest me or give me the correct code? I am also not successful using Rvest package.

```
library(XML)
dat <- readLines("http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g60763-d93450-Reviews-Grand_Hyatt_New_York-New_York_City_New_York.html", warn=FALSE)
raw2 <- htmlTreeParse(dat, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

##Rating
data <- xpathApply(raw2,"//div[@class='col2of2']//span[@class='rate sprite-rating_s rating_s']/img[@alt]",xmlValue)
Rating <- sapply(data,function(x) xmlAttrs(x)["alt"])
Result <- unlist(Rating)
Result
```

Comment: If you are a law/ToS-abiding coder, you don't (ref: http://www.tripadvisor.com/pages/terms.html), and you see about going through their [API](https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/) instead.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I am new to R and using it for my self learning purpose.

Comment: I can think of a plethora of other sites that would be better for "learning purposes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
##Rating
Result <- xpathSApply(raw2,"//div[@class='col2of2']//span[@class='rate sprite-rating_s rating_s']/img", xmlGetAttr, "alt")
```